# Flyway placeholders fails to read from Quarkus config

Tags: junit, quarkus, flyway

In quarkus 2.9.2.Final I try to configure flyway placeholders in src/test/resources/application.properties by

```
quarkus.flyway.placeholders.a=a
quarkus.flyway.placeholders.b=b
```

where in the flyway script these placeholder are used like

```
create user ${a} with password '${b}';
```

However, when I run the test which starts up db and executes flyway I get error

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder: ${a}.  Check your configuration!
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.PlaceholderReplacingReader.read(PlaceholderReplacingReader.java:165)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterReader.read(FilterReader.java:65)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.PositionTrackingReader.read(PositionTrackingReader.java:33)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterReader.read(FilterReader.java:65)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.RecordingReader.read(RecordingReader.java:33)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterReader.read(FilterReader.java:65)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.PeekingReader.refillPeekBuffer(PeekingReader.java:73)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.PeekingReader.peek(PeekingReader.java:183)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.PeekingReader.peek(PeekingReader.java:165)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.Parser.readToken(Parser.java:478)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.parser.Parser.getNextStatement(Parser.java:173)
    ... 73 more
```

I checked that my config is valid by defining a config mapping

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "quarkus.flyway")
interface MyConfig {
    Map<String,String> placeholders();
}
```

and injecting it in a service where the Map was exactly having these two elements.

So now I really wonder why flyway quarkus extension cannot handle it / which trick I am missing.

Please help, I need this simple thing to work.

Comment: What does your migration script look like?

Comment: I posted it: 
`create user ${a} with password '${b}';`

Comment: Do you have a sample application I can try? It should work, we have tests that use this feature

Answer (score 1):

Oh no I found it..small but IMO nasty one driving me crazy.
In my project, Flyway is only to be used with my named datasource 'myds'.

So config had to be changed to:

```
quarkus.flyway.myds.placeholders.a=a
quarkus.flyway.myds.placeholders.b=b
```

Would be nice to have an error message which gives a clue. But maybe it's only my fault, so I guess not worth asking for improvement in flyway.

Comment: this is beyond stupid, if you ask me. A _clear_ error message would have been great, indeed.